# Automapper not working - keeps saying unmapped property for property that has been mapped

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I'm using Automapper (automapper.extensions.microsoft.dependencyinjection) in .Net Core to map from a list of models to dto's. I've create a mapping using ForMember for a property but I keep getting an error that the property is unmapped.

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
```

```
var userRolesDtos = 
                _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserRole>, IEnumerable<UserRoleDto>>(await _userRoleService.GetUserRolesAsync(urrp)); // method return <IEnumerable<UserRole>
```

```
public class UserRole 
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserRolePermission> UserRolePermissions { get; set; } = new List<UserRolePermission>();
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateDeleted { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class UserRoleDto
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateDeleted { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserPermissionDto> UserPermissions { get; set; } = new List<UserPermissionDto>();
    }
```

```
public class UserRoleProfile : Profile
    {
        public UserRoleProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<UserRole, UserRoleForCreation>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<UserRole, UserRoleForPartialUpdate>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<UserRole, UserRoleDto>(MemberList.None)
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.UserPermissions,
                    src => src.Ignore()
                );
        }
    }
```

I expect the object to map and for the UserPermissions property to be ignored, instead I get this error:

{AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: 
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type

## For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters

AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using the current configuration.
UserRole -> UserRoleDto (Destination member list)
BIN.Core.Models.UserRoles.UserRole -> BIN.Core.Dtos.UserRoleDto (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
UserPermissions

at AutoMapper.ConfigurationValidator.AssertConfigurationIsValid(IEnumerable`1 typeMaps) in C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\ConfigurationValidator.cs:line 48
   at lambda_method(Closure , IEnumerable`1 , IEnumerable`1 , ResolutionContext )}

Comment: It looks like the `UserRoleProfile` isn't being used, is it in the same assembly as the Startup class?

Comment: Nope. That was definitely the issue.. the profile was in my business layer instead of my API layer.